# Delphi implementation of Aberth–Ehrlich method and precision errors

Tags: algorithm, delphi, math, matrix, precision

I've implemented [Aberth–Ehrlich method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method) for finding all roots of polynomial (actually it's one of steps of eigenvalues finding).
**It works very well with the degree less or equal 25**.
But when degree is larger, my Delphi calculations begin to fail.
I'm quite sure it's because an accumulation of errors of very small and very large numbers during calculations.

For an algorithm needs I've developer `TComplex = record … end;` structure based on `Double`.
The same result I got when the base data type is `Extended`.

I'm quite sure the problem is not an algorithm, because when I've updated `TComplex` to use [MPArith multi precision library](https://github.com/JulStrat/MPArith) rather, I got exactly the same results as `Octave` and `Matlab` programs - so I assume they are correct.
But in this case time of calculation is veeery slooow.

So my question are:
Do you know how to bypass multi precision issue in Delphi?
Do you think, if I'll port realization of calculation to another programming language (f.e. `C++`, `C#` or any other), I'll have no problem with the precision of calculations?
Sure, I'll have to wrap it into `dll` to call within the `Delphi` code.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: (1) In 64-bit applications, `Extended` is the same as `Double` (64-bit float). In 32-bit applications, however, `Extended` is an 80-bit float. (2) You don't need to change language. Everything you can do in C/C++/C# you can do in Delphi. (3) Library recommendation questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right about `Double` and `Extended` in Delphi. But even in x64 application the result is similar. Only when I've used `MPArith library` I was able to confirm by self that an algorithm is working but multi precision issue rather.

Comment: @Andrii: is your question about precision errors or about execution speed? You seem to have solved the precision problem. High precision comes with the price of execution time. How slow is it? What would you expect? On what machine are you benchmarking it? How much time Matlab needs to do the calculations? And above all, how crucial is it for your application? Are you writing a math library or this is part of an application? How likely and how frequently users will need to deal with a degree of 25+?

Comment: @JohnKouraklis: My question is about precision problem, speed is good: < 1 sec for 25x25 matrice when I used `Double` or `Extended` as base for my record. I guess, `Matlab` is even faster. As I mentioned above, when I used class from the `MPAryth` library as a base in my `TComplex = record … end;` class, eigenvalues for matrix 50x50 calculated > 20 mins but with correct results. Sure, something could be optimized. But anyway, this library is not so fast as regular `Double` or `Extended`, because does mostly with the memory. I used the same `TComplex` class and algorithm for both situations.

Comment: @Andrii: Once I looked at `MPAryth` library for a project but we took different direction so  didn't try it at all. If you post your question on delphipraxis there are some people who have done extensive work that involves numeric calculations and I am sure they are more well positioned to assist you

Comment: @JohnKouraklis: Did you mean delphipraxis.net? There are couple of sites.

Comment: @Adrrii: Yes, the english one here: https://en.delphipraxis.net